# Prove: $e^{x^2}$ has an antiderivative above $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration

The function $e^{x^2}$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ is it sufficient to conclude that it is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$?

If it is, we can define for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $A(x)=\int_0^x e^{t^2} \, dt$ and by using the second fundamental theorem $A(x)$ is the antiderivative?

Comment: |x| is continuous in R but is not differentiable in x=0

Comment: How can continuity and nothing else imply differentiability? If that was true, there would be no reason to use two different terms (continuous/differentiable).

Comment: Yes, $e^{x^2}$ has an antiderivative, but it is impossible to write down an expression for it (using a finite combination of elementary functions).

Comment: You don't need the integrand to be differentiable: only continuous. The fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $f$ is continuous then $F(x) = \int^x_0 f(t) dt$ is differentiable with $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know, I should have ask, to use the fundamental theorem of calculus, to show that there is an antiderivative, all I need is continuity?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It isn't unusual to call something by multiple names. E.g. in first-year linear algebra, the two terms "nonsingular" and "invertible" are used interchangeably. (Surely, the two are not equivalent when we go from fields to commutative rings, but you know what I mean.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is differentiable, and even ${\cal C}^{\infty}$, being a composition of two such functions.

Yes, the $A(x)$ you constructed is an antiderivative, whose existence was never denied.:)  What is denied is that this antiderivative can be expressed in closed from.:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however, it is a whole other question as to whether or not you can express the antiderivative in terms of elements from a given space of (elementary + some special)-functions. I believe you need [Differential Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory) or something similar to prove/disprove general statements like this.

Comment: I wish someone would explain their down vote as I fail to see anything wrong with this answer?..